# What does the new <%: %> encoding syntax in Visual Studio 2010 do?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Scott Hanselman's latest blog entry about the new VS 2010 features mentions "the new <%: %> encoding syntax". What does it do? Searching for these tags with google doesn't seem to be possible...

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It outputs HTML with the entities encoded.  It's short-hand for

```
<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Some string") %>
```

Furthermore, it can be extended to do extra cool stuff, like protecting the output against XSS, as Phil Haack [demonstrated](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx).

[Phil Haack](http://www.haacked.com/), [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu) and [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com) have blogged extensively about new and improved features in .NET 4.

Answer (score 4):

It will automatically HTML-encode the enclosed expression.

So...

```
<%: yourString %>
```

... is equivalent to ...

```
<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(yourString) %>
```

See the following MSDN link for more info:

- [HTML Encoded Code Expressions](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/#0.2__Toc253429265)

Answer (score 1):

I think it ensures that the text contained inside is sanitized, so that java script can't be injected into the page

so if you have

```
userdata = alert ("textstring")

<%= userdata %>
```

will show a messagebox in on the page

```
<%: userdata %>
```

will show the text 'alert ("textstring")'

Answer (score 1):

Actually [this Google search](http://www.google.nl/search?num=20&hl=nl&newwindow=1&q=asp.net+4+new+%22%3C%25:%22+syntax&meta=lr%3D&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) lead me to [this explanation of Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx).

Comment: This leads me to the next question: I wonder why google doesn't give any results for "<%: %>" although that string is right in the title and header of the page...

Comment: Your're right, it was a lucky search, the "<%: %>" keyword wasn't used, so Google showed the results for "asp.net 4 new syntax". Google doesn't support escaping of punctuation characters and I haven't found a workaround for it, sorry.

Comment: certainly not your fault. Thanks for the link though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its purpose is to help prevent against XSS attacks via encoding the HTML.